# Exercise pulleys and accelerations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, acceleration

[image]

The system shown has ideal massless pulleys and no friction. The pulleys 1 and 2 are fixed and the pulley 3 is mobile. The
mass m2 is rigidly attached to the center of the pulley 3 by a support without mass, and mass m1 is tied to the string, as shown. If the masses m1 and m2 are the same, what is the acceleration of the mass m1?

I tried to figure it out and got 0 but that is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The mass m2 is hanging from what is known as a [Luff tackle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_and_tackle), which has a 3:1 ratio. This means that, from the string's viewpoint, the system acts exactly like a mass of size $m2\over 3$; the inertia is one third of m2's, and the force generated by gravity is equal to $gm2\over 3$.

Since m1 and m2 are equal, this means that the system is equivalent to a simple single pulley, with mass $m$ hanging on the left and mass $m\over 3$ hanging on the right. So, the effective total mass $m_e = {4m\over 3}$, the effective force is $f_e = {{2\over 3}gm}$, and the acceleration is $a = {f_e\over m_e} = {2gm\over {4m}} = {g\over 2}$.

(It's strange that my answer isn't one of the ones shown, but I've reviewed my work and can't find any errors.)

Answer (score 0):

$m_1g - T = ma$

$3T -m_2g = ma$

Solving these, and taking $m_1=m_2$,

We get, $a=g/2$

Which is same as Daniel's answer.